# what is the difference between these two declaration in javascript

Tags: javascript

what are the difference between these two types of declaration .I think both works the same way . The first is a function object and second is a variable object when to use which please help .

```
function timers() {
    function start() {}

    function end() {}
};

var add = {
    start: function () {
        some block of code
    },
    end: function () {
        some block of code
    },
};
```

Comment: No, they don't work remotely the same way. What makes you think they do?

Comment: Right, those two pieces of code do completely different things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two are completely different.

In your first example, `start` and `end` are only accessible within `timers` and a new `start` and `end` are created every time you call `timers`. `timers` is a reference to a function. You'd use this format when you needed to have functions within `timers` that you only needed within it and not outside of it, and which would have access to information specific to the call to `timers` where they were created.

In your second example, a single object is created with `start` and `end` properties referring to functions. Those can be called via `add.start` and `add.end`. `add` is a reference to a non-function object. You'd use this when you wanted an object with functions on it that you could use via that object reference.

Answer (score 1):

**1.** `timers` is a **function declaration** which contains 2 nested functions `start` and `end`. To create a new object of `timers` you need to use the constructor function like `var objTimer = new timers();` But since the functions `start` and `end` are nested inside the `timers` and are not exposed, you can't call them like `objTimer.start()` or `objTimer.end()`.

```
 function timers() {
        function start() {}

        function end() {}
    };
```

So, if we modify the above code to something like following, returning the object which contains the members to be exposed then it would be similar to your second code.

```
 function timers() {
        function start() {}

        function end() {}

        return {
             startPublic : start,
             endPublic : end
        }
    };
```

**2.** `add` is an **object literal** which contains 2 functions `start` and `end`.  In this case, since `start` and `end` are properties are are publicly exposed, you can call them as `add.start()` and `add.end()`.

```
var add = {
    start: function () {
        some block of code
    },
    end: function () {
        some block of code
    },
};
```